# Error installing GlassFish Server (invalid SwiXML Descriptor)

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I'm trying to install GlassFish Server 3.1.2 in a Windows 7 x64 machine. The system reports me an **invalid SwiXML Descriptor error**... How can I fix this?

Comment: This must be an installer bug. Can you please point to the installer? SwiXML is the tool/framework that draws the installation wizard for you.

Comment: I'm using the latest version available on Oracle's website...

Comment: Try installing Netbeans 7.1.1 that bundles GF 3.1.2 - I  successfully installed this bundle 2 days ago.

Answer (score 3):

This was a know bug registered on OpenMQ JIRA:
http://java.net/jira/browse/MQ-33

I opened a issue for Glassfish since OpenMQ one is marked as solved:
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18757

The SwiXML error is actually related to Glassfish Configuration.
The installer runs without any trouble when option "Install only" is selected.
Nevertheless the bug will always happen when you run the installer in order to configure a installed Glassfish.

Users with such issue has an alternative path (until a fix is not released):
1- Install Glassfish using install only option
2- Configure domains manually using asadmin

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved on Unix system forcing EN language. On Unix, you have to run the installer as:

> LANG=EN ./glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh

I published an article on my blog (in Spanish) about it: http://balteus.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/error-del-instalador-unix-de-glassfish.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue and after searching the Web, couldn't find a solution but I've noticed that most the reports of this issue are localized in different languages (Japanese, Portuguese, French... and Spanish, which is my case).
It doesn't matter if Glassfish is the multilanguage or the English version, as the installer is localized itself.